# How to open Dialog after selected Date on AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, android-studio, calendarview

This is what I want and can't do. After I choose a date, I need to open a dialog with information about the date.

Can anyone help me with the code for this?

This is the code to open the method:

```
private void abrirPopUpAlSeleccionarFecha(){
    //defino los objetos de mi popup

    EditText txtNombrePersona;
    EditText txtEdadPersona;
    EditText txtFechaSeleccionada;
    EditText txtIdeasRegalo;
    Button btnCerrarPopUp;

    txtNombrePersona = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNombrePersona);
    txtEdadPersona = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEdadPersona);
    txtFechaSeleccionada = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtFechaEscogida);
    txtIdeasRegalo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtIdeasRegalo);
    btnCerrarPopUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClosePopUp);

    dialogoPopUpFechaSeleccionada.setContentView(R.layout.fecha_seleccionada_popup);
    dialogoPopUpFechaSeleccionada.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
}
```

Comment: show info in AlertDialog???

Comment: @vahab-balouchzahi how would that work?

Answer (score 0):

```
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
     View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);

    EditText txtNombrePersona;
    EditText txtEdadPersona;
    EditText txtFechaSeleccionada;
    EditText txtIdeasRegalo;
    Button btnCerrarPopUp;

    txtNombrePersona = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.txtNombrePersona);
    txtEdadPersona = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtEdadPersona);
    txtFechaSeleccionada = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtFechaEscogida);
    txtIdeasRegalo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtIdeasRegalo);
    btnCerrarPopUp = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonClosePopUp);

     builder.setView(view);
     builder.setCancelable(true);
     final Dialog dialog = builder.create();
     dialog.show();
```